# I Deleted A File, And Xcode Is Giving A Clang Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, clang

I imported a file (tlb.c), but then I (intentionally) deleted it. Now when I run the project, Xcode is giving a clang error and says that it is because it cannot find "tlb.c". I did not edit any of the original files to reference it, so I don't see any reason why it would throw this error.

I deleted it because I realized that I did not download the .h file that went with it.
I have cleaned the project, and completely restarted Xcode multiple times.

Here is the error it gives me:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Tom/Desktop/Test64iOS Resource/Test64iOS/tlb.c'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you remove the file from your project as well as delete it from disk?  If you failed to remove if from your project you'll still see it project navigator except the font will be red.

If that's not your problem, select your project root in Project Navigator and then select "build phases."  There's a "Compile Sources" section.  See if the file is listed there and remove it.

Comment: That's it! It was trying to include it in the compile sources under build phases, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this same issue on Xcode 9.1, 
I checked out the "Compile Sources" section but the file wasn't listed. I cleaned the project multiple times, tried searching my computer for the file to restore it (it wasn't anywhere to be found).

Finally, I just exited Xcode and came back. Error gone.

Comment: The easiest solutions are usually the best, this one really worked for me.